# How to create global repository

Tags: repository, global, laravel-5.1

In my application I have many Controllers like `CashInController`, `CashOutController`, `InvoiceController` etc. For each of them I have created separated Repository in my `App\Repository\` folder.

Sometimes I need same functions or Queries for many Controllers. As an example:

```
public function months()
{
    return [
        'January' => 'January',
        'February' => 'February',
        'March' => 'March',
        'April' => 'April',
        'May' => 'May',
        'June' => 'June',
        'July' => 'July',
        'August' => 'August',
        'September' => 'September',
        'October' => 'October',
        'November' => 'November',
        'December' => 'December'
    ];
}

public function clients()
{
    return Client::all()->lists('name','name')->sort();
}
```

Now, I want to create a common repository for every controllers or global functions which I can use everywhere in my application.

Comment: If you are finding a function that needs to be accessed in many controllers use Jobs.

Comment: Or you can Create BaseController and extend them others. BaseCotnroller create this global  function

Comment: @MinaAbadir Can you explain more or give some example?

Comment: @NuriddinRashidov Already `Controller` is extended. Should I replace `Controller` with `BaseController`?

Comment: @smartrahat when there is a part of code that is being repeated in many controllers. Add it to a job that runs synchronously, and call that job from any controller. This should be the best design approach.

Comment: @MinaAbadir Can you tell me how can I do that? How can I add my code to Job?

Comment: I will add that to an answer.

Comment: No i mean you can create base class that extend form laravel Controller and init that global functions in this class and extend other controllers  which u want to use this functions from this BaseController . This is one way u can use for simple task as well as

Answer (score 0):

Preferably, if you have chunk of codes that needs to be repeated in several controllers, better to add it to a Job.

#### To Use Jobs.

First add a job:

```
php artisan make:job TestJob
```

You will find a new class created under App\Jobs, add your code in the handle method:

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use App\Jobs\Job;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Bus\SelfHandling;

class TestJob extends Job implements SelfHandling
{
    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Then in any class, add the following trait, Controllers have that trait by default:

```
use DispatchesJobs;
```

Wherever you need to dispatch the job, run that code:

```
 $this->dispatch(new TestJob());
```

#### To Use Helper functions.

For simple functions, you can create Helper classes, to do that create Helper directory under App, then create a new class:

```
<?php

  class MyHelper
{
  public static function test()
  {
    return "hello";
  }
}
```

Add the class to your composer autoload, in your `composer.json`:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database",
        "app/Helpers/MyHelper.php"
```

Then in your classes do the following:

```
MyHelper::test();
```

Comment: Actually I am new in working with Laravel `Job`. There are two functions in my question. Can you please use them in `handle()`? Then I can understand how to write code in `handle()` method.

Comment: hmm, I am sorry. Those functions in specific are simple, and can be done using Helper classes. I thought you have more complex functions, that require interactions with other Laravel functionality.